# Python Flask jinja2 render input field onkeyup

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

In my app I want to check an input field e.g username if it's exists or not before continue my in form.

I'm using Flask jinja2 for templating. Here is a piece of my code:

```
 <form method="POST" action="">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="form-group col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9">
       <label for="inputUsername">User Name</label>
       {{ render_field(form.username, class="form-control rounded" onkeyup="checkUserName()") }}
       </div>
```

Of course the onkeyup attribut does not work, my question how to perform it ?

Thanks

Comment: Normally, onkeyup kicks off some javascript script. Do you have a javascript function called 'checkUserName' ?

Comment: I do have this function on my static/js/main.js

Comment: then it would be a good idea to post that script here as well. And the part of your template where js scrips are added to your base template.

Comment: After checking other python flask modules, I have found WTForm which have the possibilies to validate data input and has the custom validation which I can just use it in my python code. js here and now is useless. Thanks anyway

Comment: @koul can you also please look after this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56005424/custom-css-not-working-when-using-bootstrap-with-flask

Answer (score 0):

Using WTForms for custom validation in my case, it's the good option